# Procedure is not working as expected

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

Here is my procedure which should return a article from database, article is selected by article code which I'm sending from my C# code as a parameter called
`_searchParam`, now I run into the situation where I had article with code for example 100, and that article is deleted, and later I add new article and set its code to 100,
so now I have two articles in database with same code, with difference that one of them is deleted
and that's why I said:

```
AND T1.IsDeleted = 0;
```

but procedure returs first article with searched code (and that's deleted one), so it looks like `AND T1.IsDeleted = 0;` is ignored or it's not counting..

Procedure here:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ArticleGetArticle`(
    _searchParam varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
SELECT T1.*,T2.*,T3.Value, T3.Description
From articles as T1 LEFT JOIN barcodes as T2 ON T1.ArticleId=T2.ArticleId JOIN taxes as T3 ON T1.TaxId=T3.TaxId
Where T1.ArticleCode=_searchParam OR T2.Value=_searchParam AND T1.IsDeleted = 0;
END
```

[image]

Article with status `T1.IsDeleted = '1'` is allways returned (first one), because that's the first one that sql founds,
and I don't know why `T1.IsDeleted = '0'` in my Where clausule is ignored..

Comment: depends you have 3 conditions articlecode=searchparm OR value=searchparm and isdeleted=0 - maybe you need brackets around those to make sure its doing the right mix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T1.ArticleCode=_searchParam OR T2.Value=_searchParam AND T1.IsDeleted = 0;
```

This interpreted as

```
(T1.ArticleCode=_searchParam) OR (T2.Value=_searchParam AND T1.IsDeleted = 0);
```

Try adding your own brackets like this:

```
(T1.ArticleCode=_searchParam OR T2.Value=_searchParam) AND T1.IsDeleted = 0;
```

Comment: I will accept answer in 7 minutes, and that works. I allways making mistakes on sql side, never in my c# code :/ I need to learn a lot of more about sql queries looks like. Thanks anyway